# Rewrite rule not working on virtual host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have spent 2 days on the following problem:

I have a virtual host on an apache 2.4.7 server with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/xxx/test/www
        ServerAdmin webmaster@xxx.com
        ServerName test.xxx.com
        ServerAlias www.test.xxx.com
        AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xxx-test-error.log
        LogLevel warn
        LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xxx-test-access.log combined

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/xxx/test/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And an .htaccess file like this:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^article/([^/\.]+)/?$ article-page.php?name=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^list/.?$ list.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

I want to have all the URL started by /list/ treated with list.php

But when I lauch the URL: http://test.xxx.com/list/yyy-category

It just returns a 404. I have checked, the list.php exists and have the good rights.

I checked the logs and I got:

```
[Sun Feb 14 21:00:23.764091 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 17393] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 79.81.246.191:53329] 79.81.246.191 - - [test.xxx.com/sid#66dd81c14970][rid#66dd81b400a0/subreq] [perdir /home/xxx/test/www/] add path info postfix: /home/xxx/test/www/list.php -> /home/xxx/test/www/list.php/yyy-category, referer: http://test.xxx.com/
[Sun Feb 14 21:00:23.764163 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 17393] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 79.81.246.191:53329] 79.81.246.191 - - [test.xxx.com/sid#66dd81c14970][rid#66dd81b400a0/subreq] [perdir /home/xxx/test/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/xxx/test/www/list.php/yyy-category -> list.php/yyy-category, referer: http://test.xxx.com/
[Sun Feb 14 21:00:23.764194 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 17393] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 79.81.246.191:53329] 79.81.246.191 - - [test.xxx.com/sid#66dd81c14970][rid#66dd81b400a0/subreq] [perdir /home/xxx/test/www/] applying pattern '^article/([^/\\.]+)/?$' to uri 'list.php/yyy-category', referer: http://test.xxx.com/
[Sun Feb 14 21:00:23.764228 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 17393] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 79.81.246.191:53329] 79.81.246.191 - - [test.xxx.com/sid#66dd81c14970][rid#66dd81b400a0/subreq] [perdir /home/xxx/test/www/] add path info postfix: /home/xxx/test/www/list.php -> /home/xxx/test/www/list.php/yyy-category, referer: http://test.xxx.com/
[Sun Feb 14 21:00:23.764259 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 17393] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 79.81.246.191:53329] 79.81.246.191 - - [test.xxx.com/sid#66dd81c14970][rid#66dd81b400a0/subreq] [perdir /home/xxx/test/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/xxx/test/www/list.php/yyy-category -> list.php/yyy-category, referer: http://test.xxx.com/
[Sun Feb 14 21:00:23.764287 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 17393] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 79.81.246.191:53329] 79.81.246.191 - - [test.xxx.com/sid#66dd81c14970][rid#66dd81b400a0/subreq] [perdir /home/xxx/test/www/] applying pattern '^list/(.?)$' to uri 'list.php/yyy-category', referer: http://test.xxx.com/
[Sun Feb 14 21:00:23.764355 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 17393] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 79.81.246.191:53329] 79.81.246.191 - - [test.xxxcom/sid#66dd81c14970][rid#66dd81b400a0/subreq] [perdir /home/xxx/test/www/] add path info postfix: /home/xxx/test/www/list.php -> /home/xxx/test/www/list.php/yyy-category, referer: http://test.xxx.com/
[Sun Feb 14 21:00:23.764386 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 17393] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 79.81.246.191:53329] 79.81.246.191 - - [test.xxx.com/sid#66dd81c14970][rid#66dd81b400a0/subreq] [perdir /home/xxx/test/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/xxx/test/www/list.php/yyy-category -> list.php/yyy-category, referer: http://test.xxx.com/
[Sun Feb 14 21:00:23.764414 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 17393] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 79.81.246.191:53329] 79.81.246.191 - - [test.xxx.com/sid#66dd81c14970][rid#66dd81b400a0/subreq] [perdir /home/xxx/test/www/] applying pattern '^sitemap.xml$' to uri 'list.php/yyy-category', referer: http://test.xxx.com/
[Sun Feb 14 21:00:23.764445 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 17393] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 79.81.246.191:53329] 79.81.246.191 - - [test.xxx.com/sid#66dd81c14970][rid#66dd81b400a0/subreq] [perdir /home/xxx/test/www/] pass through /home/yyy/test/www/list.php, referer: http://test.xxx.com/
```

Any idea on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it, it's something really stupid in fact. As seen in the logs, it tries to make it match with the following file and it's not a good path

```
home/xxx/test/www/list.php/yyy-category
```

The best way not to confuse apache is not have the file with a name completeny different from the URL prefix like "list-page.php". The rule that works is now:

```
RewriteRule ^list/(.+)?$ list-page.php?query=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your .htaccess matches urls which start with "list/" and are followed by one character, or none (that's what .? means).

In your case, you have to change the rule that way:

```
RewriteRule ^list/.*$ list.php [L]
```

The **.*** symbols mean **"I want any character, 0 or more times"**.

Comment: I helped me to fix a small bug I introduced while searching but it was not the root cause. Thank you for helping me on this!